# Geometry of Complex Numbers

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, transformation, rotations

Write down in the form ${Z}\rightarrow{AZ+B}$ the following transformations of the complex plane:

(a) translation in the direction $(2,-3)$

(b) rotation about (0,1) through $\pi/4$

I know from my student answer key that the answer for
part (b) is ${Z}\rightarrow{AZ-iA+i}$

where $A=\frac{(1+i)}{\sqrt2}$

can someone explain the steps for part (b)? Part (a) is straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you find part (a) easy, I guess you understand the geometry of complex addition and how complex numbers can be thought of as vectors.

If you can't do part (b), maybe you don't understand complex *multiplication*. If you have complex numbers $z$ and $z'$, then $zz'$ is $z$ with its length multiplied by the length of $z'$, and rotated by the angle $z'$ makes with the real axis.

So for instance, if you have a complex number whose vector is of length $5$ and makes an angle of $15°$ with the horizontal, then multiplying $z$ by that complex number will make $z$ five times longer and rotate it $15°$ in the positive direction.

Comment: Yeah so I understand that a rotation will be like Z -> AZ with A=e^itheta.

But I still don't understand how the book arrived at that answer :(

Comment: @JayC If you understand that, the what would you have guessed the answer should be?

Comment: I got it!
Thanks!

I forgot to convert (0,1) to 0+i = i!
Then T(Z)-i = e^(ipi/4) * (Z-i) and I just expanded.